# In Javascript, does passing an object to another class cause memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

If class A has an object and passes it to class B, will class A be prevented from garbage collection because class B has a reference to an object in class A?

Comment: Please specify the name of the language you're trying to understand - Java and Javascript are *quite* different.

Comment: Ok, I just changed it to javascript

Comment: If B remembers the reference to A, A will not be GC'd as long as both B and B's reference to A exist. However, B should only exist as long as it is needed, and keep A's reference as long as _it_ is needed. Keeping things you don't need is indeed a cause of a memory leak; if it's just one object it is inconsequential, if you have a loop doing it on multiple references it might be catastrophic. (This has nothing to do with classes though, but individual objects.) Note that you can run out of memory on _needed_ things just like you can on junk.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr**
Object A will be garbage collected.

**Why?**
Well, every object in Javascript only lives as long as there is a reference to that object. Since at some point there is no reference to object A it will be deleted. But the shared object, lets call it object C, was never "owned" by object A, object A only had a reference to object C. Since B has still a reference to C, C will not be deleted.

**What about non reference types?**
While reference types are never owned but rather exist as a reference, primitive types a owned by their parent.

```
a = { x: "lorem ipsum" };
b = { y: a.x };
```

This means that in the above example the string "lorem ipsum" is saved twice in memory. If object a is deleted then so is the string. This doesn't effect b, because the string was copied by value, meaning that it was written a second time into memory.

**How does the runtime know what object are referenced?**
Every time the GC starts, it starts marking all objects that can be reached by references from the top scope. Everything that was not marked in this process will be deleted (in some way, depending on the type of the running GC).

Comment: So you're saying that everything in object A except object C (which is also in A) will be garbage collected?

Comment: Everything that is not a reference. If A has a second object, object D, and only A has a reference to D, then D will be garbage collected as well, since with A the last reference to D is deleted.